# Troubles with Nexus 4 Ubuntu touch - Ubuntu 13.10 connection

Tags: ubuntu-touch, 13.10, mtp, nexus-4

Each time I trying to copy anything to my Nexus 4 U Touch folders I receiving the following error

> Error while copying “IMG_20130723_220008.jpg”.
>
> There was an error copying the file into
>   mtp://[usb:001,004]/Nexus%204/Pictures.
>
> Show more details
>
> libmtp error:  Could not send object info.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Is this fully updated, as there have been several fixes/updates to **libmtp** and **MTP** recently?

Comment: What version of **Ubuntu** desktop (or whatever) is the host for this MTP transfer (over USB)?

Comment: I've already found the problem. It looks like a USB was broken... At least it works from a different port.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason for me it works for but only if a turn off the mtp sharing from nexus 4 itself while connected to my computer and then turn it back on again.

The first time I connect the nexus Nautilus shows a Nexus 4 device but no internal storage.  After restarting the mtp connection from the nexus itself, the internal storage is found and I can access everything.  I got Ubuntu 13.10